# GCP Logging - how to create logging-based metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on creating a logs-based metric using VPC Flow Logs. Within each log, there's a connection/dest_ip field in the jsonPayload. My goal is to have a metric where each series corresponds to a unique destination IP.

Is this achievable? I've attempted using the distribution type and included dest_ip as a selected field in the log-based metric creation process.

Comment: The way I will design the solution will be to create a logged based metric on all the relevant matches, whatever the dest_ip. Then, it's with Cloud Monitoring I will add a filter (agg) on the dest_ip field to raise alert or display graphs. Having 1 logged based metric per IP make not sense, it's too expensive!!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently unsure about the use case. However, I would help you with the creation of log-based metrics.

Please do each step one at a time for this to work. Look for the 'Create alert' button—it has a bell icon. You'll find it on the right side of this page, just below where you typed your query. Click on it to continue.

When you click on this button, a new window will pop up on the right side of your screen. It's titled 'Create logs-based alert policy.' In this window, you can set up alerts based on the logs you receive. These alerts will let you know whenever a log that meets certain criteria comes in. Each time this happens, an incident will be logged or assigned. You can also decide how often you want to be notified about these incidents. Additionally, you have the option to include any notes or details you want in the notification. You can use markdown, variables, and controls specific to your communication channel.

Here's what you need to do to create the alert based on the query. You can skip the optional input boxes if you want.

- Provide a policy name (mandatory)
- Optionally, include markdown or variables if your setup requires them
- Click on the "Next" button
- In the "Choose logs to include in the alert" step, paste the scaleup event query provided at [2] for one alert
- Proceed to the Notification frequency setting and select a value that aligns with your needs (e.g., 5 minutes, 1 hour, etc.)
- In the final step, specify your notification channel (created on the Notification channels page)
- Finally, click on the "Save" button

I hope this helps, yo may find more about Log Based metrics [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics)